# Check equality of an objects array property and a nested object property

Tags: javascript

On my app I'm checking the equality between an objects array property and a nested object property - based on the results I return a new objects array.

The `items` objects array:

```
[{name: 'test345', value: 1, category: 'a'},{name: 'test2high', value: 2, category: 'b'},{name: 'test3low', value: 3, category: 'c'}]
```

The `itemCategories` object:

```
{testnum1: {name: 'test123', category: 'a', partialName: '345'}, testnum2: {name: 'test234', category: 'b', partialName: 'hight'}
```

I need to check the equality between the `category` properties and return the following objects array:

```
[{name: 'test', itemCategory: 'testnum1'},{name: 'test2', itemCategory: 'testnum2'}]
```

Below is what I did, it works fine, now I need to add a second check based on the `item`'s name: I need to only return the items that their names include the `partialName`, any idea on how to adjust this?

```
export function getCategorizedItems(items) {
  const categories = new Map(
    Object.entries(itemCategories).map(([itemCategory, {category}]) => [
      category,
      itemCategory
    ])
  )

  return items
    .map(item => ({
      value: item.value,
      category: categories.get(item.category)
    }))
    .filter(({category}) => category)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic approach be

- 1. create a comparison function
- 2. iterate over the items array

```js
const items = [{name: 'test345', value: 1, category: 'a'},{name: 'test2high', value: 2, category: 'b'},{name: 'test3low', value: 3, category: 'c'}]
const itemCategories = {testnum1: {name: 'test123', category: 'a', partialName: '345'}, testnum2: {name: 'test234', category: 'b', partialName: 'hight'}}

const isEqual = (item, icItem) => {
  return item.name.match(new RegExp(icItem.partialName + '$'))
  && item.category === icItem.category
}

const keyValues = Object.entries(itemCategories)
const res = items.flatMap(item => {
  const itemCategory = keyValues.find(([, value]) => isEqual(item, value))
  if (!itemCategory) return []

  // return whatever you want based on item, key, value
  return { item, itemCategory }
})

console.log('res', res)
```

If you prefer to use map (for the category lookup e.g) then you may store more data on the map (as value)

```js
const items = [{name: 'test345', value: 1, category: 'a'},{name: 'test2high', value: 2, category: 'b'},{name: 'test3low', value: 3, category: 'c'}]
const itemCategories = {testnum1: {name: 'test123', category: 'a', partialName: '345'}, testnum2: {name: 'test234', category: 'b', partialName: 'hight'}}

const isEqual = (item, icItem) => {
  return item.name.match(new RegExp(icItem.partialName + '$'))
  && item.category === icItem.category
}

const categoryToIc = new Map(Object.entries(itemCategories).map(([key, icItem]) => [icItem.category, { icItem, key }]))
const res = items.flatMap(item => {
  const el = categoryToIc.get(item.category)
  if (!el || !isEqual(item, el.icItem)) return []

  // return whatever you want based on item, key, value
  return { item, itemCategory: [el.key, el.icItem] }
})
console.log('res', res)
```